# How to hide Bootstrap 5 modal programatically in react?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

How to hide Bootstrap 5 modal programmatically in React?

I have tried this:

```
const myModal = document.getElementById("dis-approve-modal");
myModal.hide();
```

but it says "hide is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure this not the right way to do it -via HTML element properties-

but if you want to do it this way try

```
myModal.hidden = true;
```

Comment: Only hides the modal but leaves the greyed out background.